# Como remover área de interesse do background de uma imagem?

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens, inteligência-artificial

Estou começando a trabalhar com processamento de imagens no reconhecimento de padroes, e estou precisando fazer pre processamento das imagens que utilizarei. Primeiro, eu preciso destacar a regiao de interesse do background da imagem, alguem pode me indicar qual a melhor tecnica para isso? Estou utilizando o opencv mais python para este procedimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segundo, eu preciso identificar as cores dessa regiao de interesse e plotar um grafico 3d.

Comment: Não sei que tipo de análise você deseja, pode ser um histograma simples de cor. Ou eu estava lendo recentemente: [este artigo](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5624802), que utiliza o [EMD](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/emd.html) bidimensional para fotos com cores.

Comment: Certo, vou da uma lida. quanto a remoçao do background e destacar somente a area de interesse, vc tem alguma dica de tecnica?

Comment: @danieltakeshi quero classificar as cores dessas manchas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para extrair você pode utilizar o [Grab Cut](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/de/dd0/grabcut_8cpp-example.html) do OpenCV

Um [exemplo pode ser visto no tutorial "Interactive Foreground Extraction using GrabCut Algorithm"](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html)

#### Código

Utilizando o código do exemplo:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\teste\\FHB9o.jpg')

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (10,10,45,45)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]
cv2.imshow('Imagem', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\teste\\resultado.jpg', img)
plt.imshow(img),plt.colorbar(),plt.show()
```

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

#### Observação

Neste caso o ROI (Região de Interesse) retangular é fixo. Caso as imagens possuam variação na localização do objeto que precisa ser extraído, um ROI dinâmico precisa ser criado, em que os contornos serão os pontos que determinarão as coordenadas do ROI dinâmico.

Comment: deu certo, obgdo. Voce pode me ajudar nessa? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52707256/how-to-remove-hair-noise-from-skin-images-using-opencv

Comment: Creio que você pode fazer um teste com contornos Canny, depois filtrar os objetos pela área do contorno. Esperando que os contornos sejam menores do que o objeto que deseja detectar.

Comment: @CarlosDiego Este é um site do Stack Overflow em português, favor falar em português. E se tem uma dúvida em JavaScript, favor realizar uma nova pergunta.